# Male and Female functions

Tags: lateral-thinking

You are given two goniometric functions:

- Male: $g(\rho, \Theta) = \rho \, \cos\Theta \sin\Theta$
- Female: $f(\rho, \Theta) = \rho \, \cos^2\Theta$

**Why are these two functions labeled *"male"* and *"female"*?**

Comment: Now explain me why the female's value at 90° is 0...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe

> cos = X-chromosome and 
>  sin = Y-chromosome 
>  Male = XY = cos * sin 
>  Female = XX = cos * cos

Comment: Also, you can mention the relation between the X coordinate and cos and the Y coordinate and sin.

Comment: @dmg : It is X & Y 'chromosomes', you must have misread  as 'coordinates' :)

Comment: On the contrary, in the unit circle the cosine of the angle is equal to the displacement of X, the sine of the angle is the displacement of Y. That is why cos is X and sin is Y and not the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, got your point.

Comment: Next time I see pronoun conflict on the horizon, instead of asking for gender, I'll ask for f(ρ,Θ)